# Google Civic Api - electionquery

Tags: google-civic-information-api

Hello Support Engineer Team,

I am trying to use the GET https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/elections
route to inquire for respective elections and by retrieving the electionId, I am using Elections: voterInfoQuery route I am trying to gather Contest and candidate information

Two questions:

1. If I am running the election query now as of 11/27/2020, It only shows me two elections and I feel it is missing some of information like Georgia Runoff election and all.
2. How can I query the election route to gather information for past elections like elections which just got finished (Nov 3, 2020) ?